# Нужна помощь с кортежами и словарями Python

Tags: python

Вводится список названий городов в одну строку через пробел. Перебрать все эти названия с помощью цикла for и определить, начинается ли название следующего города на последнюю букву предыдущего города в список. Если последними встречаются буквы 'ь', 'и', то берется следующая с конца буква слова. Вывести на экран ДА, если последовательность удовлетворяет правилу, и НЕТ – иначе. Вот такая задача, не понимаю как ее сделать. Помогите

Comment: На жаль на цьому сайті питання задаються тільки російською мовою.

Comment: Да вроде всё понятно написано в задании, бери да пиши. Вы начните хотя бы, а будут трудности - поможем. А так чтобы с нуля за вас задание делать - это не сюда.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос

Comment: Буквы можно оставить в вопросе такие какие есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cities_string = "Харків Воронеж"
cities = (c.strip("ь").strip('і') for c in cities_string.split())
letter = next(cities)[-1]

for c in cities:
    if c[0].lower() != letter:
        print("НЕТ")
        break
    letter = c[-1]
else:
    print("ДА")
```

П.С. В этом решении нет кортежей.

Comment: Минусовал не я. Но зачем делать за человека задание, которое прямо по шагам расписано уже? Хотя я и сам иногда грешен. Но если всё чётко расписано и осталось только запрограммировать, то человек ничему не научится если сделать за него.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А как человек научится если ему не объяснять? Для меня это задание не понятное было, у меня даже примеров не было как это можно реализовать

Comment: @DenisKolisnichenko в этом ответе есть пара моментов, которых обычно нет в учебниках для "непрограммистов" так что разберитесь что значит каждая строчка чтоб это сдать очно. но лучше перепишите это другим алгоритмом

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @CrazyElf если ему нужно, то тут можно увидеть несколько особенностей языка, которые нужно будет посмотреть. Это подтолкнет к изучению больше чем если бы он написал набор букв "на бэйсике" в попытке это решить.

Comment: @CrazyElf а минусы - цена развлечений)